# Insertion in ordered linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to insert a node in a linked list so that the nodes are ordered in ascending mode by de idx parameter.

```
    void add(int i){
    if(find(i)==NULL){ //if node does not exist
        node *m=new node;
        m->idx=i;
        m->values=NULL;
        m->next=NULL;
        if(list==NULL){ //if list is empty
            list=m; 
            return;     
        }           
        if(i < list->idx){ //if the new node comes before the head node
            m->next=list;
            list=m;
            return;         
        }
        //if the new node is bigger than the maximum node index in the list
        if(i > maxIdx(list)){
            node *last=lastNode(list);
            last->next=m;           
        }
        //else normal insertion
        node *prev=list;
        node *curr=list->next;
        while(curr!=NULL){
            if( i < curr->idx){
                m->next=curr;
                prev->next=m;
                return;             
            }
            prev=curr;
            curr=curr->next;
        }
    }   
}
```

Edited with correct implementation, the fourth if was missing before.

Comment: I'm a beginner, this is not homework. I'm able to do head or tail insertion, and now I'm trying to make ordered insertion.

Comment: What is the relationship between `mrow` and `node` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's homework or not in this case, as the question is not "how to write ..", or "please write me ..". It's about a specific error in existing code. Anyway, @Vektor88 - where does the seg fault occurs? Which like, at least?

Comment: mrow is a node, I forgot to edit those lines.

Comment: Any idea where the seg fault occurs? Use a debugger to find out.

Comment: It seems correct to me as well, as far as segfault is concerned. However, you don't consider the case when `i` is greater than the largest number in the list. In this case, you should insert the `i` at the end of the list.

Comment: @Nawaz that was the problem, now valgrind doesn't complain anymore!

Comment: @Vektor88: Hehe.. .in that case, my comment is actually the answer. So I posted it as answer :D

Comment: If you want an ordered container with fast insertion/removal, I suggest you use `std::set`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems correct to me as well, as far as segfault is concerned. However, you don't consider the case when `i` is greater than the largest number in the list. In this case, you should insert `i` at the end of the list. So try fixing this bug first, maybe it will fix the segfault as well (which is coming from elsewhere, maybe from your `find()` implementation).

Now it seems that is the answer (as your comment on my comment confirms it).